# Listview Adapter class with search filter not sending exact position while searching

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, position

I'm trying to make an application that will show details of a `ListView` row on click. I added a filter and three `EditText`s for search options.

I if I use all options for searching , my app shows one member three times, that's why I commented out two of the conditions in the filter() method.

But the main problem is while I'm searching for a member it searches well but when clicking on the search result it seems the position of the `ListView` row changed. For example, if I found three search results the first one is on position 0, second on position 1 , and third one on position 2.

The Listview click event works fine without searching.

I need the old position like it was before filtering to send it via an `Intent` to another `Activity` that will show different data for each member.

**ListViewAdapter.java class**
`

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    mContext = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}
@Override
public WorldPopulation getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
          .getCountry());
    holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
          .getPopulation());
    // Set the results into ImageView
    holder.flag.setImageResource(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
                    .getFlag());

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(mContext,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("Integer", position);
            summaryIntent.putExtras(b);
            mContext.startActivity(summaryIntent);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Position:" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
           // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
           // depending on "position", for example

           // Pass all data rank
           //  intent.putExtra("rank",
           //      (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank()));
           // ...likewise pass all other data ...

           mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    worldpopulationlist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText) ) {
                worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
            }
            if(wp.getRank().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
            }
            if (wp.getPopulation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: do you mean you need the "position" like it was before filtering?

Comment: yes. i only need the old position. is it necessary to keep the getView() method? or need to use convertView as i need to show 300-400 list. i don't understand. i also want to remove the unnecessary code from here.  @0X0nosugar

Comment: if you want to edit your question, there is a small field "edit" below the "android" tag at the bottom.

Comment: for now i only need to get the old position having the search filter working properly. that's all.please help.

Comment: arraylist.indexOf( getItem(position) ) should give you the "old" position for the "onClick()" method

Comment: Wow Great.it's working now.Thanks a lot. but is it possible to add 300-400 list item in this getView() method? @0X0nosugar

Comment: how can i ignore getting same list three times. is there any way to do this? @0X0nosugar

Comment: 1. I think the number of "data rows" in arraylist will be somehow limited by RAM. So you need to write the data to a SQLite database table and then load it from there as needed (user scrolling --> load new data) At this point many of us think it's  worth the time to learn how to use a CursorLoader/ SimpleCursorAdapter.   -   2. don't evaluate the filter conditions independently (--> logical "or" ) OR just set a boolean to "true" and later on evaluate the boolean before adding anything to the list

Comment: i declare a boolean value. such as boolean b=true; at the start of my filter. but can't apply statement for the other two.please help.@0X0nosugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the "old" position of an item in the `onCLick()` method, use

```
arraylist.indexOf( getItem(position) )
```

Change your filter method like this to avoid multiple adding of the same item:

```
// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
worldpopulationlist.clear();
if (charText.length() == 0) {
    worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
} 
else {
    boolean addToList;

    for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) {
        addToList = false;

        if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                 .contains(charText) ) {
            addToList = true;
        }
        if(wp.getRank().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                  .contains(charText)) {
            addToList = true;
        }
        if (wp.getPopulation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                   .contains(charText)) {
            addToList = true;
        }

        // now add the item to your list if it matches the search criteria
        if (addToList) {                      
            worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
        }

    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: wow.works great..before i set Boolean as true. and thinking if i set false inside other condition then what happen =D. i got my exact search result off as Boolean is only carry true=1; false=0. But now this works fine. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Imraj Hossain - you're welcome :) -please let me know if you'd like me to edit your question (which indeed was a little difficult to understand, but now I know what the problem was). And then you could wait a while if someone posts a better solution ("there's more than one way to do it" ;-) ) and finally mark one of the working answers as accepted (grey check mark on the top left of the answer)

Comment: yes .sure if you want you can also delete the unnecessary coding and also unnecessary comment inside. :) @0X0nosugar

Comment: @Imraj Hossain - done :) - I left out the "second activity" code because I never had to look at it while helping you

Comment: @Imraj Hossain - ideally one would show only what is necessary to reproduce the problem, so for example I could even have left out the ImageView. If you are using libraries, you should mention that. But imports of "normal" classes like Toast or ArrayList are not worth mentioning. Writing a good question takes time, sometimes more than searching for the answer on your own. If you always try to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, in many cases you will find out what went wrong simply by isolating the problem from the rest of the application.